# Inserting a comma(,) in the bibliography generated by BibLateX

Tags: bibliographies

I want to insert a comma at the position shown below.

Bib file is as follows:

```
@Article{GS08,
    author = {Groth, J. and Sahai, A.},
    title = {Efficient Non-interactive Proof Systems for Bilinear Groups},
    journal = {Advances in Cryptology - EUROCRYPT'08},
    year = 2008,
    volume = {Springer LNCS volume 4965},
    pages = {415-432}
}
```

MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Paper.bib}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
\cite{GS08}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And finally I want to insert a a comma between journal and volume

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't you use the `incollection` entry type, rather than `article`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the `xpatch` package. I changed your entry type to `@InProceedings`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{Paper.bib}
@InProceedings{GS08,
    author = {Groth, J. and Sahai, A.},
    title = {Efficient Non-interactive Proof Systems for Bilinear Groups},
    booktitle= {Advances in Cryptology -- EUROCRYPT'08},
    year = 2008,
    series = {Springer LNCS},
    number = {4965},
    pages = {415-432}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{Paper.bib}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}

\usepackage{xpatch}
%
\xpatchbibdriver{inproceedings}{%
 \newunit\newblock
 \usebibmacro{series+number}%
 }{%
 \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}\newblock
 \usebibmacro{series+number}%
 }{}{}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
\cite{GS08}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It exactly solved my problem. Can you explain in a sentence or two how is the patching being done?

Comment: It' quite simple:The `\xpatch…` commands have 4 arguments: the first is the fragment of code to be replaced (here in  the `inproceedings` bib driver, but it might be a bibmacro as well)); the second is the replacement text; the third and fourth (generally unused) are commands to be executed in case of success or failure, respectively. Of course the text to be replaced must be unambiguously defined in the original code.